# pass index to child event listener in parent component in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I have a list of objects within a v-for loop:

```
<div v-for="(element, index) in myArray">
    <child @event-fired="handleEvent(index, dataFromChild)"></child>
</div>
```

Now I want once the event is fired from the child component, on my `handleEvent` method, pass the index and the data from the child component.

But now, if I do something like stated above,I get an error on console stating, `property or method dataFromChild is not defined....`

Comment: FYI, camel-cased event names are often difficult to work with. Vue recommends using kebab-cased, ie `@event-fired`

Comment: @Phil thanks, will consider that from now on, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind an arrow function expression in your event handler. For example

```html
<child @event-fired="dataFromChild => handleEvent(index, dataFromChild)"/>
```

JSFiddle demo (from the Vue boilerplate) ~ https://jsfiddle.net/zmxksv35/

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the event and the index in the event listener.

```
<child @event-fired="handleEvent($event,index)"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just pass everything into your event handler as a single object.

```html
<div v-for="(element, index) in myArray">
    <child @event-fired="data => handleEvent({ index, data })"></child>
</div>
```

Then, in your event handler, you can destructure it:

```
handleEvent({ index, data }) {
    // handle the event
}
```

Comment: @Johhn Ah, I misunderstood what `dataFromChild` represents.